How to Use a Client Certificate for OAuth 2.0 in a Custom Connector in Power Automate?
I have an external API that requires OAuth 2.0 authentication, and part of this flow involves the use of a client certificate. The issue I'm facing is that when setting up a Custom Connector in Power Automate, I don't see any built-in option to upload or reference a client certificate.
I understand that client certificate authentication is a common requirement for securing API calls, but I’m unsure how to integrate this into the Power Automate Custom Connector.

Is there an alternative approach or workaround to include a client certificate in the OAuth 2.0 flow within Power Automate’s Custom Connector?

Is there any other method to securely authenticate the API requests that require a client certificate using Power Automate?


I appreciate any guidance or examples from anyone who has faced a similar challenge.
